Chrome Android PWA beforeinstallprompt not firing , works on desktop
the javascript beforeinstallprompt listener is not working on Chrome Android version , it does work on desktop version, the manifest file has 0 errors and service worker is registered.
Can this be related with the dom loading order and manifest file is taking more time to load on mobile than desktop ?
Thanks in advance...
I tried 2 different Android phones, samsung galaxy and google pixel same error, also browserstack emulators and same error... it works perfect on chrome @ desktop... I tried with entering an email into a login form to play with the "engagement heuristic" and same problem...
